# Auto-refresh DIVs in a rendered partial (jQuery/Rails)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, partials

**BACKGROUND:** For a chat app I'm rendering a partial of all messages in the chat. Each instance of the partial is rendered with the following (time_ago being a custom method) :

```
<%= message.message %><span class="time_ago"><%= time_ago(message) %></span>
```

When a user submits a new message, I use an AJAX call to update the chat with the new message using the following (from create.js.erb file) :

> $("#chat_messages").append("<%= escape_javascript render @message %>");

**ISSUE:** After X amount of time, I'd like to auto refresh the time_ago span for each message in the partial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [TimeAgo plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/). It works awesomely.

Answer (score 0):

With javascript you should get `$("chat_messages")`, iterate it's rows, and for each span wich has the class **time_ago** you should update the content.